# Using IN clause in ADO.net commands

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have not done `ADO.NET` before and the part I am working on still doesn't have enough data, database, etc that I can run a quick example by myself to test it yet so just writing the code for now to run and test later here is part of the code I have:

```
Company.Framework.Data.Sql.DataReader drPkcr = new Company.Framework.Data.Sql.DataReader();

drPkcr.CommandText = "Select PKCR.* "
                     + "From PRIMARYKEYSCROSSREFERENCE PKCR "
                     + "Where PKCR.REFERENCE_VALUE = @hospitalId And "
                     +
                     "PKCR.KEY_VALUE IN (SELECT REFTABLE_K FROM REFTABLE WHERE REFERENCEMASTER_K = '        18' AND ACTIVE = 1 AND DELETED = 0)";

drPkcr.Parameters.Add("hospitalId", hospitalId);
```

I am a little worried about the `IN Clause` part. Is it valid for `ADO.NET` to do that? I did search and found other questions with `IN clauses` but they were passing parametrized values to their IN clause. As you see my `IN clause` doesn't have values that change. So I wanted to know if this is valid for ADO.NET to run?

Comment: Is that accurate in your Query `WHERE REFERENCEMASTER_K = '        18' AND ACTIVE = 1 AND DELETED = 0)"` in regards to the number of Spaces you have... also have you thought about creating this as a Stored Procedure.. also do you have access to Sql Server Enterprise Manager..where you can run the query as well as take advantage of some of it's Optomizing features..?

Comment: @MethodMan yes the number of spaces, etc is correct. It is how we save them in DB. But No I can't use stored procedures, etc...just have to follow along the lines of other similar queries I see in the code, and they are like this...so I just want to know if I can have a IN clause like this?

Comment: ADO will not touch/modify/be aware of the IN clause, it will be passed to the database and executed there.

Comment: @AlexK. Ok so does that mean this is valid?

Comment: Understandable how many spaces are there exactly think that you can clean this up my utilizing the `string spaceNum = new String(' ', 12')` for example that way you can pass the spaces as a variable

Comment: Its syntactically correct for most databases

Comment: @AlexK. Great. Ok thank you. Yes it is SQL Server 2008 or the version after that.

Comment: You are basically doing what is called a `Sub Query` and at first glance it the query looks to be accurate code in regards to the `IN` Clause.. I will look at it more in detail to see if I see any inefficiencies for SQL Server the syntax looks correct btw..

Comment: With those spaces in the Database I wonder if you couldn't utilize the `Trim()` Function as well but you would be the only one to determine if what you are expecting returns correctly from the database once adding the `Trim()` to the query.. just an Idea / suggestion btw

Comment: Bear in mind TRIM() in the query would kill any index use on the column